# Actions Must be Plain Objects - React Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-redux, redux-thunk

Actions must be a plain object error. The Edit button on the projectList component should trigger a slide out window that displays the details of the project and allows the project to be edited. Once the window is closed it should then refresh the projectList page.

I've created async functions for the relevant actions but am still receiving the error.

ProjectActions.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const SET_SELECTED_PROJECT = 'SET_SELECTED_PROJECT';
export const UPDATE_PROJECT = 'UPDATE_PROJECT';

export const addProject = (project) => ({
    type: 'ADD_PROJECT',
    payload: project,
});

export const removeProject = (projectId) => ({
    type: 'REMOVE_PROJECT',
    payload: projectId,
});

export async function setSelectedProject(dispatch, getState) {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/');
    dispatch({
        type: SET_SELECTED_PROJECT,
        payload: response.data,
    });
}

export function updateProject(project) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/projects/${project.id}`, project);
        const updatedProject = response.data;
  
        // Dispatch a plain object action with the updated project data
        dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_PROJECT,
          payload: updatedProject,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error here
      }
    };
  }

export const setShowDetails = (showDetails) => ({
    type: 'SET_SHOW_DETAILS',
    payload: showDetails,
});

export const fetchProject = (projectId) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/projects/${projectId}`);
        dispatch({
            type: SET_SELECTED_PROJECT,
            payload: res.data,
        
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

ProjectList.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ProjectForm from './ProjectAddForm'; // Correct component name
import ProjectEditForm from './ProjectEditForm'; // Correct component name
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProjectDetails from './ProjectDetails';
import Popup from './Popup';
import {
  addProject,
  removeProject,
  setSelectedProject,
  setShowDetails
} from '../actions/projectActions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  projects: state.project.projects,
  showDetails: state.project.showDetails,
  selectedProject: state.project.selectedProject,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { 
  addProject,
  removeProject,
  setSelectedProject,
};

const ProjectList = ({  addProject, removeProject }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [redirectToProjects, setRedirectToProjects] = useState(false);
  const [isPopupClosed, setIsPopupClosed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(null);
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/')
      .then((res) => {
        setProjects(res.data);
        if (isPopupClosed) {
          setRedirectToProjects(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [isPopupClosed]);

  const openPopup = (projectToEdit) => {
    setSelectedProject(projectToEdit);
    setShowPopup(true);
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setShowPopup(false);
    setIsPopupClosed(true);
  };

  const clickedProject = new Set();

  const handleEditClick = (project) => {
    console.log('Edit button clicked', project);
    if (!clickedProject.has(project.id)) {
      clickedProject.add(project.id);
      setSelectedProject(project);
      // setShowDetails(true);

      // dispatch(setSelectedProject(project));
      dispatch(setShowDetails(true));
    }
  };

  const handleCloseDetails = () => {
    setShowDetails(false);
    setSelectedProject(null);
  };

  const handleProjectAdded = () => {
    // Handle project added successfully (e.g., show success message)
    // For now, we'll just close the popup
    closePopup();
  };

  const handleAddProject = () => {
    const newProject = {name: 'New Project'};
    addProject(newProject);
  };

  const renderProjects = () => {
    return (
      <table className="table">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Project Name</th>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Budget</th>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Start Date</th>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>End Date</th>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Status</th>
            <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {projects.map((project) => (
            <tr key={project.id}>
              <td>{project.project_name}</td>
              <td>{project.budget}</td>
              <td>{project.start_date}</td>
              <td>{project.end_date}</td>
              <td>{project.status}</td>
              <td>
              <button onClick={() => handleEditClick(project)} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
              
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };

  //<Link to={`/edit-project/${project.id}`}>Edit</Link>

  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Project List</h1>
    <button onClick={() => openPopup(null)} className="btn btn-primary">
      Add Project
    </button>
    {showDetails && (
      <div className="side-out-container">
        <span onClick={handleCloseDetails} className="close">
          &times;
        </span>
        <ProjectDetails project={selectedProject} onClose={handleCloseDetails} />
      </div>
)}

    {showPopup && (
      <Popup
        onClose={closePopup}
        onProjectAdded={handleProjectAdded}
        projectData={selectedProject}
        formType={selectedProject ? 'edit' : 'add'}
        setProject={setSelectedProject}
      />
    )} 
    {redirectToProjects && (window.location.href = '/')}
    {renderProjects()}
  </div>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectList);
```

ProjectDetails.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setSelectedProject, updateProject } from '../actions/projectActions';

const ProjectDetails = ({ 
  selectedProject,
  setSelectedProject,
  updateProject
}) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState(selectedProject);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormInputs(selectedProject);
  }, [selectedProject]);
  
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setFormInputs({
      ...formInputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleUpdateProject = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateProject(formInputs);
    setSelectedProject(null);
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  // if (isEditing) {
  //   return (
  //     <form onSubmit={handleUpdateProject}>
  //       <label>
  //         Project Name:
  //         <input type="text" name="project_name" value={formInputs.project_name} onChange={handleInputChange} />
  //       </label>
  //       {/* Add other form inputs for other fields */}
  //       <button type="submit">Update Project</button>
  //     </form>
  //   );
  // }
  return (
    <div>
      {selectedProject ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Project Details</h2>
          {isEditing ? (
            <form onSubmit={handleUpdateProject}>
              <label>
                Project Name:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="project_name"
                  value={formInputs.project_name}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </label>
              {/* Add other form inputs for other fields */}
              <button type="submit">Update Project</button>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <p>Project Name: {selectedProject.project_name}</p>
              <p>Budget: {selectedProject.budget}</p>
              {/* Other project details */}
              <button onClick={handleEditClick} className="btn btn-primary">
                Edit Project
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No project selected.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  selectedProject: state.project.selectedProject,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateProject, setSelectedProject })(ProjectDetails);
```

Store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

Comment: Your Redux store appears to be missing the proper middleware to handle non-object actions, creating more asynchronous actions isn't how this is resolved. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] showing how the Redux store is created.

Comment: Edited to include details of the store. redux-thunk is installd.

Answer (score 0):

The [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) function takes up to three arguments: root reducer, *initial state*, and then enhancers, in this order.

> ```
> createStore(reducer, preloadedState?, enhancer?)
> ```

I believe you just need to pass an initial state value as the second argument, moving the middlewares to the third.

Examples:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  undefined, // or any initial state value, maybe persisted state
  applyMiddleware([thunk])
);
```

However, it is highly advisable to update and use [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) (RTK) and [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore). `configureStore` takes a single options argument, so initial state would only be provide if it was necessary/required. RTK integrates Thunk middleware by default, so there is no additional setup/configuration necessary.

Basic example:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});
```

See [Customizing the Included Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware) for more details what can be configured.

Comment: Thanks for your input Drew. I'm made the changes but still receving the same error message.

Comment: @LewisNorthcott Bummer. See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we can inspect live.